# Python Spinbox Format Behaves Differently On Windows Versus Linux

Tags: python, windows-7, tkinter

Here is my code:

```
   self._image_set_number = Spinbox(self._ramp_group, from_=0, to=999, command=self.reset_rep, format="%03.0f")
   self._repetition_change = Spinbox(self._ramp_group, from_=00, to=99, format="%02.0f")
```

On Linux, the spinners behave as expected.  There are always three digits in `_image_set_number` and two digits in `_repetition_change`.  The values are padded on the left by zeros.  When I use the small arrows to increase the value, it works as expected.

But, on Windows 7 64-bit, the small arrows do not behave as expected.  They go up to `008` and then go back to `000` on the next click.  Am I missing something or is this a bug in the the Windows version of Tkinter?

Comment: Are you using different versions of Python? Works as expected on Windows 7, Python 2.5. Have you tried adjusting the `increment` to something like 10, to see if it's the value (008) or the amount of clicks that's giving a problem? Is `_repetition_change` having the same issue?

Comment: I'm using Python 2.7.  It's not the number of clicks that causes the problem.  It's clicking the arrow from 008 to 009 that causes it to reset to 000.   It happens in both Spinner objects.

Comment: FWIW, just tried it on 2.7, and behavior is like you described. Sorry I can't be of more help--it is weird, and is most likely OS and version specific.

Comment: I added a ticket in the Python bug tracker: http://bugs.python.org/issue21303#

Comment: Good call. I think it has something to do with the string `format` method, which would explain why it worked in 2.5 but not 2.7 (`format` was implemented in 2.6). Totally not sure, but that's my guess.